# Spring Security Role Prefix and Custom User Details Service

Tags: spring-security, roles, security-roles

How do I set the role prefix to `""` with a custom user details service in Spring?

```
    <beans:bean id="authService" class="com.cisco.badges.business.services.AuthenticationService"/>

<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
                <salt-source ref="saltSource" />
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

---

```
@Service("authService")
public class AuthenticationService extends BaseService implements UserDetailsService, IAuthenticationService {

    @Autowired
    IUserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    IAuthorityRepository authorityRepository;

    public AuthenticationService() {

    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if(user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user with username '" + username + "' found!");

        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            authList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getName()));
        }

        UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getEnabled() == 0 ? false : true, true, true, true, authList);

        userAuthentication.setSalt(user.getSalt());
        userAuthentication.setId(user.getId());

        return (UserDetails)userAuthentication;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
```

just like this

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to append a `_ROLE` to your current roles using a mapper. In Spring Boot:

```
@Bean
public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper grantedAuthoritiesMapper() {
    SimpleAuthorityMapper simpleMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
    simpleMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

    return simpleMapper;
}
```

After that you should add this mapper to your provider:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setAuthoritiesMapper(authoritiesMapper());

    return provider;
}
```