# Spring Security roles should always be prefixed with ROLE?

Tags: spring, spring-security

In our application we are using Spring Security and we observed that if the role names are not prefixed with ROLE , it does not work.

Our roles are configured in DB and there is no restriction on the name given to a role.

Is there any work around to avoid the ROLE prefix to roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a solution here: [Spring Security – adding a custom Role Prefix](http://bluefoot.info/howtos/spring-security-adding-a-custom-role-prefix/), according to which you just need to configure the `RoleVoter`:

```
<beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
```

See also [Spring Security Role Prefix and Custom User Details Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951832/spring-security-role-prefix-and-custom-user-details-service).

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I haven't noticed this behavior.

In my project I'm using Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE with Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE. And my securityContext.xml contains the following lines:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied.do"
               entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.do" access="hasAnyRole('PROJECT_REVIEW', 'PROJECT_ADMINISTRATOR')"/>
    <!-- Skipped -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('PROJECT_REVIEW', 'PROJECT_ADMINISTRATOR')"/>
    <!-- Skipped -->
</security:http>
```

So, I'm using my custom roles PROJECT_REVIEW, PROJECT_ADMINISTRATOR. And it works fine.

Could you please tell what error do you get?