# Spring security added prefix "ROLE_" to all roles name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, roles

I have this code in my Web Security Config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();

}
```

So I added an user with "ADMIN" role in my database and I always get 403 error when I tryed loggin with this user, then I enabled log for spring and I found this line:

```
2015-10-18 23:13:24.112 DEBUG 4899 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/user/login; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')]
```

Why Spring Security is looking for "ROLE_ADMIN" instead "ADMIN"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security Role Prefix and Custom User Details Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951832/spring-security-role-prefix-and-custom-user-details-service)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Spring security adds the prefix "**ROLE_**" by default.

If you want this removed or changed, take a look at

[How to change role from interceptor-url?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180201001929/http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/51066-how-to-change-role-from-interceptor-url)

EDIT: found this as well:
[Spring Security remove RoleVoter prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620076/spring-security-remove-rolevoter-prefix)

Comment: Just a question, does Spring add ROLE_ by default if I add a role in @Secured annotation? Like If I add @Secured("abc"), will Spring check for ROLE_abc or just abc?

Comment: @SajibAcharya you can change the default `ROLE_`. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134121/how-do-i-remove-the-role-prefix-from-spring-security-with-javaconfig/38970309#38970309

Answer (score 24):

In Spring 4, there are two methods `hasAuthority()` and `hasAnyAuthority()` defined in `org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot` class. These two methods checks only your custom role name **without** adding `ROLE_` prefix. Definition as follows:

```
public final boolean hasAuthority(String authority) {
    return hasAnyAuthority(authority);
}
public final boolean hasAnyAuthority(String... authorities) {
    return hasAnyAuthorityName(null, authorities);
}
private boolean hasAnyAuthorityName(String prefix, String... roles) {
    Set<String> roleSet = getAuthoritySet();

    for (String role : roles) {
        String defaultedRole = getRoleWithDefaultPrefix(prefix, role);
        if (roleSet.contains(defaultedRole)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
private static String getRoleWithDefaultPrefix(String defaultRolePrefix, String role) {
    if (role == null) {
        return role;
    }
    if (defaultRolePrefix == null || defaultRolePrefix.length() == 0) {
        return role;
    }
    if (role.startsWith(defaultRolePrefix)) {
        return role;
    }
    return defaultRolePrefix + role;
}
```

Example usage:

> ```
> <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" pattern="/user/**"
>       entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
>     <!--If we use hasAnyAuthority, we can remove ROLE_ prefix-->
>     <intercept-url pattern="/user/home/yoneticiler" access="hasAnyAuthority('FULL_ADMIN','ADMIN')"/>
>     <intercept-url pattern="/user/home/addUser" access="hasAnyAuthority('FULL_ADMIN','ADMIN')"/>
>     <intercept-url pattern="/user/home/addUserGroup" access="hasAuthority('FULL_ADMIN')"/>
>     <intercept-url pattern="/user/home/deleteUserGroup" access="hasAuthority('FULL_ADMIN')"/>
>     <intercept-url pattern="/user/home/**" access="hasAnyAuthority('FULL_ADMIN','ADMIN','EDITOR','NORMAL')"/>
>     <access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
>     <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"/>
>     <logout logout-url="/user/logout"
>             invalidate-session="true"
>             logout-success-url="/user/index?logout"/>
>     <!-- enable csrf protection -->
>     <csrf/>
> </http>   <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
>             class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
>     <beans:constructor-arg value="/user"/>
> </beans:bean>
> ```

Answer (score 11):

As @olyanren said, you can use `hasAuthority()` method in Spring 4 instead of `hasRole()`. I am adding JavaConfig example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/**")
    .access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
    .and()
    .httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a mapper to add `ROLE_` at the beginning of all of your roles:

```
@Bean
public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper authoritiesMapper() {
    SimpleAuthorityMapper mapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
    mapper.setPrefix("ROLE_"); // this line is not required 
    mapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true); // convert your roles to uppercase
    mapper.setDefaultAuthority("USER"); // set a default role

    return mapper;
}
```

The you should add the mapper to your provider:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    // your config ...
    provider.setAuthoritiesMapper(authoritiesMapper());

    return provider;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

_ROLE prefix is used by spring security, to identify that it is as a role. A role has a set of privileges a.k.a Authorities, these authorities define varies permissions for a role.
    ex:-  EDIT_PROFILE, DELETE_PROFILE

You can define both the roles and authorities, if you are defining a role then it must be prefixed with "ROLE_"

In your case you are looking for a role, so by default spring security looks for a string that is prefixed with "ROLE_".