# Spring Security @Secured annotation and User authorities

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is about `Spring` v.4 (MVC + Security). I have implemented `UserDetailsServiceImpl`, where inside the `loadUserByUsername` method a user is granted with its authorities. Let's say it's simply:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    ...     
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
    
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, enabled, true, true, true, authorities);
    ...
}
```

And there is a security controller inside which there is an annotated method with the `@Secured` annotation:

```
@Secured("ADMIN")
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String users(Model model ...) { ... }
```

As you can see inside the `loadUserByUsername` method I explicitly granted the `ADMIN` role to the user.
But when I'm trying access the `/users` I get an `Access is denied` exception:

> 2016-04-19 10:25:16,899 DEBUG (http-nio-8080-exec-9)
> [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] -
> Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to
> AccessDeniedHandler
> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is
> denied    at
> org.springframework.security.access.vote.AbstractAccessDecisionManager.checkAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(AbstractAccessDecisionManager.java:70)
> at
> org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:88)
> at
> org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
> at
> org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
> ...

(without the `@Secured` annotation everything works fine).

What have I missed here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring security added prefix "ROLE\_" to all roles name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205236/spring-security-added-prefix-role-to-all-roles-name)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Without knowing this fact it is impossible to find mentioned question.

Comment: Hi, I found this question by reviewing the close vote queue (from the duplicate vote). It looks like it applies. Do you agree? (I ask that because you didn't accept it as a dupe so I don't want to close it too quickly, maybe I'm missing something).

Comment: Dear @Tunaki, I guess it was shown to you, because ndrone already coupled it with my one. When I was searching my issue, I didn't found anything similar. Please notice that if potential OP will in same situation as mine, he wouldn't know anything about `ROLE_` prefix. He will search for the question why standard configuration can not work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Surprisingly, but the problem was with the roles names. Due to the  `defaultRolePrefix` set to the `ROLE_` (see `org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter` class) all roles should have names starting with the `ROLE_` prefix. In other words, when I've changed

`authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));`
to

`authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));`

and `@Secured("ADMIN")` to `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")` - everything became fine.

Comment: It happens when you set new role extendng WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, just like you said.
However, if you set the roles in your own implementation of UserDetails (via UserDetailsService), that problem doesnt happen.

Answer (score 10):

I also faced this issue. Spring Security 4 automatically prefixes any role with `ROLE_`. Refer to the [Spring Security 3.x to 4.x migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-role-prefixing) for more details.

### Disabling `ROLE_` prefixing

As suggested in the migration guide, the following [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) can be used to disable the automatic `ROLE_` prefixing:

```java
public class DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, 
                                                        PriorityOrdered {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {

        // Remove this if you are not using JSR-250
        if (bean instanceof Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource) {
            ((Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null);
        }

        if (bean instanceof DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) {
            ((DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null);
        }

        if (bean instanceof DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) {
            ((DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null);
        }

        if (bean instanceof SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter) {
            ((SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter)bean).setRolePrefix("");
        }

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return PriorityOrdered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Then define it as a bean:

```java
@Bean
public static DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor defaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor() {
    return new DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor();
}
```

### Checking authorities

Alternatively you can check the authorities using the [`@PreAuthorize`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PreAuthorize.html) annotation:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
```

Ensure that [`prePostEnabled`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.html#prePostEnabled--) is enabled:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```