# Issue with security by url with role

Tags: spring, spring-security

In a class who extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
I have this code to add security by url for different role.

```
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/rest/setup/defaultpassword/**").hasRole("USER");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/rest/setup/commerces/**").hasRole("USER");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/rest/setup/tax").hasRole("USER");

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/setup/tax").hasRole("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll(); //
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

    http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
    http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
    http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
```

When I log with a user role, I can access: /rest/setup/tax

When I log with a admin role, I can access /rest/setup/tax

http://localhost:8080/rest/setup/tax 403 (Forbidden)

i search to provide only the get for user role and everything for admin one.

Answer (score 0):

Table AUTHORITIES will have two columns like username, authority and the role specified in column authority should be with prefix ROLE_ e.g. ROLE_ADMIN & ROLE_USER. Therefore your code should specify `hasRole("ROLE_USER")` and `hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")`

**UPDATE:**

1. RoleVoter.java

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.java

2. SO for similar issue on ROLE_ prefix

[Spring security added prefix "ROLE_" to all roles name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205236/spring-security-added-prefix-role-to-all-roles-name)

Comment: hasRole([role])
 

doc said: hasRole Returns true if the current principal has the specified role. By default if the supplied role does not start with 'ROLE_' it will be added. This can be customized by modifying the defaultRolePrefix on doc DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.

Comment: Bernard, we implemented `Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE` and had similar issue when role without ROLE_ prefix was specified. The reason  being RoleVoter class using prefix ROLE_.
I suggest to read the update link above. Note: you can also eliminate the ROLE_ prefix but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Sorry, just a minor correction. The above should read "we implemented our project using `Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE`".

Comment: funny I add ROLE_ application don't start. complete error: justpaste.it/wn96  with 4.04 don't seem to work.

Comment: Bernard, I don't know how to help you. You may give the github sample on `Spring-Security` a try at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples. It might help you to provide some insight.

Comment: Just another thought, we also have something like this to link to the login page
`http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
.loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")`

Comment: i posted on github in the spring security.... wait an answer.... seem a basic case...