# Spring Security intercept URL not working with custom UserDetails object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm really new to spring security so please please be patient. I am open to suggestions to make this question more specific if someone could guide me.

My problem is that I have an intercept-url configuration in Spring security but it is always redirecting to the access denied page even when the user has the requisite role. This is my Spring security config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login"
            session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management>

        <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="emailId" password-parameter="pwd" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <csrf token-repository-ref="tokenRepository" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Through my research I felt that there was nothing wrong in the above configuration but it could be a problem because of the custom UserDetails object that I am using. This is the POJO:

```
public class CustomUser implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String userID;
    private String emailId;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled = true;
    private boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    private boolean accountNonLocked = true;
    private List<Role> authorities;

    @Override
    public List<Role> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }
    //other setters and getters
}
```

Role class:

```
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I also have a custom UserDAO class that populates the CustomUser POJO and I have verified that there is no issue in setting of values.

This is my Principle(as written in the logs):

```
Principal: CustomUser [userID=user1, emailId=test@test.com, password=pwd, enabled=true, accountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, authorities=[Role [name=ADMIN]]];
```

What could be the reason that the pages are always denied?

Thanks for taking the time to read this whole post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changed**

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

**to**

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
```

**Edit**

If previous solution didn't work then try this way.

See in your role it returns "ADMIN" and you expect "ROLE_ADMIN"

**change role name into table**

"ADMIN" to "ROLE_ADMIN"

Comment: "ROLE_" is a predefined prefix that Spring security adds to all roles AFAIK. However, I did try your suggestion but it did not help. The issue still persists.

Comment: Check this out: [Spring Security adds a prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33206127/6345100)

Comment: Are you serious? You changed your answer 3 times and the third time you've copied from the answer I posted. Come on, man!

Comment: You know what? I'll be the bigger person and give you this answer and delete mine to avoid redundancy. If this post helps someone else, it doesn't matter if the answer is from me or you. Enjoy your new points.